# How to set timeout while doing a net.DialTCP in golang?

Tags: go

As `net.DialTCP` seems like the only way to get `net.TCPConn`, I'm not sure how to set timeouts while doing the `DialTCP`. https://golang.org/pkg/net/#DialTCP

```
func connectAddress(addr *net.TCPAddr, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    start := time.Now()
    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Dial failed for address: %s, err: %s", addr.String(), err.Error())
        return err
    }
    elasped := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("Connected to address: %s in %dms", addr.String(), elasped.Nanoseconds()/1000000)
    conn.Close()
    wg.Done()
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [net.Dialer](https://godoc.org/net#Dialer) with either the [Timeout](https://godoc.org/net#Dialer.Timeout) or [Deadline](https://godoc.org/net#Dialer.Deadline) fields set.

```
d := net.Dialer{Timeout: timeout}
conn, err := d.Dial("tcp", addr)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```

A variation is to call [Dialer.DialContext](https://godoc.org/net#Dialer.DialContext) with a [deadline](https://godoc.org/context#WithDeadline) or [timeout](https://godoc.org/context#WithTimeout) applied to the context.

Type assert to `*net.TCPConn` if you specifically need that type instead of a `net.Conn`:

```
tcpConn, ok := conn.(*net.TCPConn)
```

Comment: Is `Timeout` field counted as a counterpart for curl's `--connect-timeout`? Or is that like `--max-time`?

Comment: As a side note, net.Dial() will try to resolve the address while net.DialTCP() does not. This can be a performance concern or not, depending on you use case

Comment: The problem is that `net.DialTCP` is not completly the same as net.Dialer{}.Dial the first one has localAddr parameter but general dialer not.

Comment: @Oleg Use the dialer's [LocalAddr](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Dialer.LocalAddr) field to specify the local address.

Answer (score 10):

One can use `net.DialTimeout`:

```
func DialTimeout(network, address string, timeout time.Duration) (Conn, error)
    DialTimeout acts like Dial but takes a timeout.

    The timeout includes name resolution, if required. When using TCP, and the
    host in the address parameter resolves to multiple IP addresses, the timeout
    is spread over each consecutive dial, such that each is given an appropriate
    fraction of the time to connect.

    See func Dial for a description of the network and address parameters.
```